# Unexpected results from ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0**

---

I want to use `ListContourPlot` and I have lists such that,

```
x1 = {0, 2, 4, 6};
y1 = {1, 3, 5, 7};
R1 = {5, 6, 7, 8};
data = Table[{x1[[i]], y1[[i]], R1[[i]]}, {i, 1, 4}];
ListContourPlot[data, DataRange -> {{0, 6}, {1, 7}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

> [image: plot]

When $x1=0$ and $y1=1$ the contour must show that $R1=5$ but I see that it has a contour with a value $1$, not correct. Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: I think you need more data to make the correct contour.

Answer (score 5):

It seems `DataRange` option works incorrectly in this case. I recommend reporting it as a bug to the tech support. As a workaround you could use `InterpolationOrder -> 0`:

```
ListContourPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

> [image: plot]